# C++ How to make a std::list of arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, matrix

I have a class that contains a 2D array.

```
int arr[3][3];
```

How would I go about storing that matrix in a std::list?

```
list<*> explored;

explored.pushback(classname->arr);
```

I thought maybe because I already knew the size of the arrays I would just create a list of pointers with something like the above but that obviously doesn't work. How would I initialize the list? How would I go about accessing the 2D arrays individually?

Edit: I wanted to have a list of multiple 2D arrays. Meaning each index position would hold an array. In order to solve my problem I instead decided to make a class, have the class hold a matrix. Then I would simply get the matrix by doing something like

```
Class Node{
    Int matrix[3][3];
}
//Store a node with a matrix inside of it.
list<node> v;
v.pushback(node);


//retrieve the matrix by iterating to that position in the list then
v.matrix;
```

Answer (score 8):

> How would I go about storing that matrix in a std::list?

You cannot store raw arrays in a `std::list`.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list,

> `T` must meet the requirements of [*CopyAssignable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable) and [*CopyConstructible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible) (until C++11).
>
> The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that element type is a complete type and meets the requirements of [*Erasable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Erasable), but many member functions impose stricter requirements (since C++11, until C++17).

Raw arrays do not meet any of those requirements.

However, you may use:

1. `std::list` of `std::array`.
2. Create a `struct` that holds the array and then use `std::list` of the `struct`.

Unless you intend to add any behavior to the array, I would recomment using the first option.

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace std;

list<list<int>> matrix;
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) 
{
     std::list<int> rowList;
     for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
     {
          rowList.push_back(arr[row][col]);             
     }
     matrix.push_back(rowList);
}
```

Since elements of a matrix are more traditionally accessed directly (like an array), `std::vector` actually makes more sense.  Similar to above, except replace `list` with `vector`.

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix;
matrix.resize(3);
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) 
{
     auto& row = matrix[row];
     row.resize(3);
     for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
     {
         row[col] = arr[row][col];             
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you did a `list<array<int, x>> temp`, (where `x` is the length of your array)?

You can then iterate through the array first, then use `push_back` to add the array to the back of the list.